# Different ways to switch a user on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-storm, server-administration

I have a server running Linux `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`.  Generally I use a user named *ubuntu*.

Recently I tried to install Storm on this server and I created a dedicated user *storm* for this purpose.

Accidentally because of a typo, I realized something different when switching from *ubuntu* to *storm*.

If I switch using the following command `sudo su storm`, everything runs fine.

However if I switch using `sudo su - storm`, the storm program won't be started correctly.  Although both commands have brought me under the storm user correctly.

Anyone can help me to explain why?  Thanks.

T.E.

Comment: su - means you want the use act like a root, and use environment settings of root. So it is might because you use normal environment settings with sudo su storm; and sudo su - storm, thus using root settings.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu system administration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good link describing the [difference between hyphen and no hyphen su](https://superuser.com/questions/453988/whats-the-difference-between-su-with-and-without-hyphen). I'm guessing no-dash works for you because the environment variables are left alone.